# How can I put classes in each other in c++?

Tags: c++, class, object, struct, orientation

My task is to write a class that represents a knight (name,level,xp),and he could have maximum 10 item (it have to be another class) (item_name,value)

So, I would like to do something like this, but with classes, how can i manage to do it?

```
struct item
{
    char itemName[21];
    int value;
};

struct knight
{
   char name[21];
   int xp;
   int level;
   struct item cucc[10];
};
```

Comment: `struct`s *are* classes in C++, they just have a different default accessibility modifier.

Comment: How do *you* think it should be done? What happens when you try that?

Comment: Why are you writing `struct item cucc[10];` instead of just `item cucc[10];` in C++?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I put classes in each other in c++?

Well, just nest them, if that's what you mean:

```
struct knight
{
    struct item
    {
        char itemName[21];
        int value;
    };

    char name[21];
    int xp;
    int level;
    item cucc[10]; // Notice, that the struct keyword isn't necessary here
};
```

**UPDATE:** (after thinking a bit better about the question you *actually* meant to ask)

> So, I would like to do something like this, but with classes, how can i manage to do it?

First of all, `struct`s are classes in C++. But what you mean is probably *"How do I encapsulate this data into classes and establish a directed association between them?"*

In this case, I'd go for something like this:

```
class item
{
public:
    // The constructor to set an item's name and value
    item(std::string name, int value);
    // Supposing your item's names and values don't change,
    // so only getters on the class's interface
    std::string get_name() const;
    int get_value() const;
private:
    // Member variables are private (encapsulated).
    std::string itemName;
    int value;
};

// Skipping member function definitions. You should provide them.

class knight
{
public:
    // The constructor to set a knight's name
    knight(std::string name);
    // Supposing the name is unchangeable, only getters on the interface
    std::string get_name() const;
    // ...
    // What goes here very much depends on the logic of your application
    // ...
private:
    std::string name;
    int xp;
    int level;
    std::vector<item> cucc; // If you need reference semantics, consider
                            // std::vector<std::shared_ptr<item>> instead
};

// Skipping member function definitions. You should provide them.
```

Comment: I don't think this is what they meant. They're asking how to convert them to `class`es (I think).

Comment: @sftrabbit they did ask how to put classes in each other though :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza I *think* they mean as a member :/

Comment: @sftrabbit: I admit I should have though about the intended meaning of the question a bit longer, but the title was just so misleading.

Answer (score 1):

> So, I would like to do something like this, but with classes, how can i manage to do it?

You already have. The `struct` keyword defines a class in C++, just as the `class` keyword does; the only difference is that the default visibility is public instead of private for classes introduced with `struct`.

Also, note that, after the `item` class's definition, `struct item` and `item` name the exact same type; C++ doesn't have the separation between types and struct tags that C has.

See section 9 of the C++11 standard (or the [n3337 final working draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), which is freely available) for details. In particular, **9.1 Class names** starts off with:

> A class definition introduces a new type. *[Example:*

```
struct X { int a; };
```

It goes on to explain that this declaration introduces the class name into the scope, clarifying what `struct X` on its own means depending on whether or not `X` is in scope, etc.

The difference between `struct` and `class` is discussed later in **11 Member access control** and **11.2 Accessibility of base classes and base class members**:

> Members of a class defined with the keyword class are private by default. Members of a class defined with the keywords struct or union are public by default.

…

> In the absence of an *access-specifier* for a base class, public is assumed when the derived class is defined with the *class-key* `struct` and private is assumed when the class is defined with the *class-key* `class`.

Answer (score 0):

Classes and Structs (I use these terms semantically, not syntactically --- see below) can be arbitrarily nested:

```
#include <string>
#include <array>

struct Knight {
  struct Item {
    std::string name;
    int value;
  };

  std::string name;
  int xp;
  int level;
  std::array<Item,10> cucc; // us an `std::vector` if the size is *not* fixed  
};
```

Regarding Classes: There is very little difference between structs and classes, syntactically, but there *should* be made a distinction on what you intend an object to be. If it's merely an aggregation of data it's conceptually a Struct and this should be indicated by using the `struct` keyword. If it is an intelligent data structure and manages its own private members through member functions, it's conceptually a Class, so it's typically declared with the `class` keyword.

However, syntactically `class` and `struct` only change the default visibility of members and parent types (`class` implicitly `private`, `struct` implicitly `public`).